# What is the difference between `man` and `man (#)`?

Tags: manpage

Just saw someone referencing `man 7 regex` on Stackoverflow. I tried `man regex` and got very similar output - there appear to be slight differences.

So what is this magical number 7? Searching `man 7 unix` on Google gives me more mysterious results like UNIX(7)...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### About `UNIX(7)`

To answer your question of "UNIX(7)", this is standard convention of saying "The man page for UNIX in section 7 (miscellaneous)".

To open a page like `init(8)`, you would use this command: [`man 8 init`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man8/init.8.html).

---

### `man regex` vs `man 7 regex`

To answer your question of the 'subtle differences' between [`man regex`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man3/regex.3.html) and [`man 7 regex`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man7/regex.7.html):

`man` by default opens the page with the *lowest* section number. In this case, it is section 3 (Library calls). Opening the page from section 7 (Miscellaneous) is quite different.

Pages in different sections address different things, though in this case they are similar, consider `apt`:

[`man -f apt`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=apt):

```
apt (8)              - Advanced Package Tool
apt (1)              - annotation processing tool
```

In this example, `apt` from section 8 (System administration commands) is completely unrelated to the page from section 1 (Executable programs or shell commands).

For future reference, use `man -f PAGE_NAME` to locate all pages with that name in all sections. You can then open a page from the section you want with `man SECTION PAGE_NAME`.

#### Manpage sections

The various page sections are as follows and can be found from [`man man`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man1/man.1.html):

> 1. Executable programs or shell commands
> 2. System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
> 3. Library calls (functions within program libraries)
> 4. Special files (usually found in `/dev`)
> 5. File formats and conventions eg `/etc/passwd`
> 6. Games
> 7. Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages  and  conventions), e.g. `man(7)`, `groff(7)`
> 8. System administration commands (usually only for root)
> 9. Kernel routines [Non standard]

Answer (score 14):

**The section numbers**

`man` will show the manpage from any section, `man 7` will show the manpage from section 7. So, here 7 refers to the section of the particular command for which you are looking for the manual page.

A       section,  if  provided, will direct man to look only in that section of
       the manual.

---

**The sections**

See the following table for the section numbers of the manual followed by the
       types of pages they contain.

> 1:   Executable programs or shell commands
>
> 2:   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
>
> 3:   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
>
> 4:   Special files (usually found in /dev)
>
> 5:   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
>
> 6:   Games
>
> 7:   Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages  and  conventions), e.g.
>              man(7), groff(7)
>
> 8:   System administration commands (usually only for root).     Overviews of various topics, conventions and protocols,
>                    character set standards, and miscellaneous other things.
>
> 9:   Kernel routines [Non standard]

---

**Commands in more than one section**

In most of the cases you will want to use the `man` command without additional *n*. However, in some cases a command will appear in more than one section. For example if you issue the command `man open`, you get the man page for openvt from section 1. But if you need to see the man page for open as a C (or system call, as per the above table) command, you need to issue `man 2 open`.

A very similar example will be `man printf` and `man 3 printf`. Please issue the commands and see for yourself the difference in output.

---

**Your issue of `man 7 unix` (UNIX(7))**

So, that UNIX(7) means that it belongs to section 7.

---

**Which section will be shown by default if I do not provide a section number?**

The default action is to search in all  of  the  available
sections, following a pre-defined order and to show only the first page
found, even if page exists in several sections.

---

**How do I know the section number of a command?**

Should you need to find out what sections a term/command falls in with `man -k` (equivalent to the apropos command). So,   `man -k printf`
           will search the short descriptions and manual page names for the keyword   printf  as  regular expression.  Print out any matches.  (Equivalent  to `apropos -r printf`). Issue the command, see the ton you get. If need to avoid substring matches,  (e.g. it will show sprintf if you run `man -k printf`), so you need to use `^term` to limit it, as below,

```
man -k '^printf'
Printf (3o)          - Formatted output functions.
printf (1)           - format and print data
printf (3)           - formatted output conversion
```

---

**Related command**

A related command is `apropos` as indicated above, which  searches the manual page names and descriptions. If you are not sure which manual page you are looking for but have a general idea, use this command.

Comment: But the documentation for `regex` does not have 7 sections...

Comment: @adityamenon Please see the updated answer, it got posted before finished.

Comment: I see - so a 'Section' here means "classification of program".

Comment: @adityamenon Right you are, I would have been more comfortable with the term you are using.

Comment: Specifically, "section" here means "section of The Manual", as if all of the man pages were in a single (thick) printed manual

Comment: @JonathanCallen That is an interesting observation, I must say. From my early days I have some mental hindrance accepting this word (section) to classify man page. A dumb question, what is wrong with `chapter'?

Comment: @MMA It's not important, but I think 'sections' are more appropriate because they imply more separation than 'chapters'. For my personal use, I don't refer to section 3 because I almost never program in C. It's almost completely unrelated to section one (just from my point of view).