# Confusion in command line interpreter

Tags: command-line, manpage

I installed manual doc for linux programmer on Ubuntu using Synaptic for French documentation.
But when I run `man printf` to see the documentation of `printf()` in C library `stdio.h`, I dont get this. I get this:

```
PRINTF(1)                          Commandes                         PRINTF(1)
NOM
       Printf - Formater et afficher des données
SYNOPSIS
       printf FORMAT [PARAMÈTRE] ...
       printf OPTION
```

But I obtain the correct output for `scanf` as I want in french.
An ideas?

Comment: You need `man 3 printf` - see [What is the difference between `man` and `man (#)`?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365548/what-is-the-difference-between-man-and-man/365549#365549)

Comment: @steeldriver Should this be closed as a duplicate? Or do you think it's better to have an answer here? That `printf` in particular is a command as well as a C function surprises a lot of newcomers to Unix-like operating systems.

Comment: @EliahKagan I dunno - it's not really a duplicate *question* - perhaps a nice answer that explains why this happens for printf but not for scanf and linking to the other answer as a more general reference for man sections?

Comment: @steeldriver Do you want to write that answer? If not, then I can probably write it when I get back.

Comment: I think it is actually a dupe. @hackthatos, you are seeing the manual page of the `printf` command. The manual of the C function `printf` is in section 3 (as explained in the duplicate) so you need `man 3 printf`.

Comment: Ok, I tried, It successed. But how to have the answer in the orginal version **bold**?